# listener not trigger when using local bloc (bloc: parameter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a bloc which has global state (BlocProvider is initialised before Material App). In the onPreesed callback of a button I have a bloc listener:

```
BlocListener<RiskAssesmentValueCubit, RiskAssesmentValueState>(
                    bloc: riskAss
                      ..checkActualVersusCalculated(user.customerId, riskAttitudeQuestionsDetails),
                    listener: (BuildContext context, RiskAssesmentValueState state) {
                      print('Listener called');

                      if (state is RiskAssesmentValueDifferent) {
                        print('Listener called');
                      }
                    },
                  );
```

the bloc: param is calling the method in the cubit correctly. The states in the cubit are updating. But the listener is never triggered. I grab the bloc in the build method

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final RiskAssesmentValueCubit riskAss = context.read<RiskAssesmentValueCubit>();

.....
}
```

I tried a builder and that is also not being triggered. I think I might not understand the bloc: param correctly. But I think I should be able to access the builder/listener.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are emitting `RiskAssesmentValueState` state from the `checkActualVersusCalculated()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your bloc file.
I think your need to ***emit(RiskAssesmentValueDifferent)*** or other emit your need when press button.
And note that if your func is async, your need to add ***await - async*** to your event